# Query aliased association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I query an aliased association in Rails?

I have the following models:

```
class TaxableEntity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :accountant, class_name: User, foreign_key: :accountant_id
  has_many :invoices
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taxable_entities, foreign_key: :accountant_id
  enum role: [:account_holder, :accountant, :admin]
end
```

I'm trying to do this query:

```
TaxableEntity.joins(:accountant).where(accountant: { deactivated: true })
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "accountant"
       LINE 1: ..."."id" = "taxable_entities"."accountant_id" WHERE "accountan...
                                                                    ^
       : SELECT "taxable_entities".* FROM "taxable_entities" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "taxable_entities"."accountant_id" WHERE "accountant"."deactivated" = 't'
```

I've also tried changing `accountant` to `user` and I get a similar error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Rails isn't smart enough to figure out that `where(accountant: { deactivated: true })` relates to your User model through the `:accountant` association, so you'll have to write it as

```
TaxableEntity.joins(:accountant).where(users: { deactivated: true })
```

Please note that it's `users`, plural